# How to get nam working with ns2 simulator

Tags: networking, simulation, ns2, nam

Currently I have installed ns2 in my linux pc and when I run the following on terminal

```
$ ns sampleprog.tcl
```

all I get is

```
nam:
```

There should have been a nam pop up window opening instead.
I don't know how to solve this problem as I have installed both ns2 and nam. I think it is due to me updating my Ubuntu 22.04 with which nam also got updated and is now not compatible with version of ns2. Before update nam was working fine.
How should I go about solving this problem or maybe possibly degrading the version?

I tried updating to the latest version but to no avail. The network animator window that i was expecting doesn't open

Comment: Files.tcl are to be run with `$ ns file.tcl` . ... About NAM: The current `nam` package from Debian/Ubuntu is corrupt ( `nam` also was corrupt years 2014 - 2017) . ... Valid packages  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn%27t-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced same problem in my nam 1.15 version,I downloaded nam 1.14 Deb file from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dkNPNN23Vy6o_zT0uIRBgUAo1VCXcVOY/view) a lower version.
After downloading Deb file .Open terminal in folder where nam 1.14 Deb file is downloaded And run this command.

$sudo dpkg --install nam_1.14_amd64.deb

This solved my problem.